# Enabling system management privileges for non-local users - How the heck does `polkit` work, anyways?

Tags: ssh, centos, ssh-tunneling

I am managing a CentOS 6.2 server remotely using X over SSH (actually NX, but that's just a proxy).

The Everything is working correctly, *except* when I try to do tasks that would normally require administrative permissions (such as things in `palimpsest`, or any other GUI tools).

When I try to do things which would trigger a authentication dialog (through `polkit-gnome`)the permissions dialog is silently failing, and the software is running as my user account, rather then root.

To clarify, if I change package settings using the package manager at the local console, I get a pop-up - "Authentication is required to (add/remove) packages".

If I do this remotely, the authentication fails, and I get a "Authorization Failed" dialog.

It seems to boil down to policykit configuration, but I've followed the polkit man pages, and edited my configuration, and it hasn't changed anything.

---

I can manage packages/do super-user stuff from the command line without any problems. However, I am very visually oriented, and much prefer a GUI when possible.

---

Ok, so it seems that I need to add a new rule to policykit.

Going off the man pages, I created a file (named `20-remote-admin-allow.pkla`), and dropped it into `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`. Since there seems to be multiple polkit config directories, I copied the same file into `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`.

It does not appear to have changed anything.

Here is my config file, as mentioned above:

```
[root@cloaica zul]# cat /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-remote-admin-allow.pkla 
[Let remote users do admin stuff]
Identity=unix-user:zul
Action=*
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=auth_self_keep

[root@cloaica zul]# cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/20-remote-admin-allow.pkla 
[Allow Remote Administraton]
Identity=unix-user:zul
Action=*
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=auth_admin
[root@cloaica zul]#
```

`pkaction --verbose` still reports

```
implicit any:      no
implicit inactive: no
```

for most actions, and said actions fail if I attempt them, with "Authentication Failed" dialog, as mentioned above.

Seriously, I does anyone actually understand how polkit actually works?

Policykit seems to be an ongoing nightmare, and considering *there used to be a GUI configuration tool* **and it was removed**, I don't understand how anyone thought this was ready for release into a production OS.

---

To be clear, I *like* having the "please authenticate to perform this action" dialogs. I just want to actually *have* them, rather then having the system silently fail to authenticate.

I don't want to remove the entirety of polkit, just make it either think all sessions are active, or that inactive sessions get the same permissions as active sessions.

Comment: I have no experience in CentOS, but it seems a PolicyKit related problem. The default conf on Debian and Ubuntu gives no privilege to a nonlocal user.

Comment: @enzotib - I would guess it's something like that. Now, where is is the setting that controls those privileges?

Comment: They are in `/etc/polkit-1` and `/var/lib/polkit-1`. See also `pkaction --verbose` output and `pklocalauthority` man page.

Comment: @enzotib - I've done that, see updated question. It hasn't helped.

Comment: Some remarks: 1) the file must have `.pkla` extension; 2) there should be `Identity` and not `AdminIdentities`; 3) `pkaction` returns information for registered actions (found in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/*`) and do not show local modifications, so it is better to try than believe in `pkaction`.

Comment: @enzotib - 1: Both files are `*.pkla` files. 2: Didn't make any difference. 3: Then what's the point of `pkaction`? That's ridiculously stupid.

Comment: @enzotib - see updated question

Comment: I still see an `Identities` instead of `Identity` on the first file, don't know if it is important.

Comment: @enzotib - Good catch. I've updated the question.

Comment: Weird. It now *kind* of works... For instance, `system-config-lvm` correctly prompts for the administrator password. `gpk-application` and `palimpsest`do not.

Comment: and `pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.udisks.linux-lvm2` is dropping me into the `pkcheck` man pages, despite the fact that the man pages say `pkcheck --action-id action {--process { pid | pid,pid-start-time }`

Comment: I needed to run `systemctl restart polkit` after creating the `.pkla` file. https://serverfault.com/questions/1078535/centos-admin-user-on-xrdp-session-cant-do-admin

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for certain you're having the exact same problem, but this is listed as a fedora [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=750530), as of Nov, 2011. I installed a clean CentOS 6, upgraded all packages and then had the same problem trying to remotely access and add a new package (something requiring auth).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have trouble with this as well. Specifically with udisk.

(I'm running Ubuntu desktop 14.04)

To fix for udisks I did this.

1. Backup and edit

   `sudo vi /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks.policy`
2. look for all the:

   `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>`

   and then change the:

   `<allow_any>no</allow_any>`

to:

```
   `<allow_any>yes</allow_any>`
```

this allows remote access rather than just froce local only

Comment: FYI, the changes made via this method will most likely be overwritten by a udisk upgrade. Better to place a suitable file into, for example, the `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[Remote Admin SSH access] 
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

After this add the user to users group. Do you see any security issues with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found that running:

```
 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &
```

first in my ssh session allows me to get the normal auth popup as if I was local.

With this, I'm able to run gnome-disks or any other gnome utility that needs auth_admin.

This binary comes from the `policykit-1-gnome` package.