# Make reboot work only with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, reboot

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.06. I am able to execute `reboot` command as a non-root user without `sudo`. How can I change this behaviour so that I am not able to run `reboot` without `sudo`? I tried checking where `reboot` actually points:

```
user:~$ which reboot
/sbin/reboot
user:/sbin$ ls -l reboot
reboot -> /bin/systemctl
```

But I do not know how to change `systemctl` behaviour.

Comment: post results for ls -l /bin/systemctl it is probably in a group with the bit suid active for your personal user.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini this is a regular executable file.

Comment: Because that you need to post the ls -l for it.

Comment: `user:/sbin$ ls -l /bin/systemctl` returns
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 659848 feb 15 16:11 /bin/systemctl`

Comment: Try that: chmod  o-x /bin/systemctl and guarantee your user are not in the group root.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini this will work, so I would use this for now, but on my other machine when I type `reboot` I get `reboot: Need to be root` and permissions on reboot are exactly the same.

Comment: I think it is related to the configuration on /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy take a look on that article http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enable-shutdown-and-reboot-for-a-normal-user-in-debian-jessie/ (i think you can do the reverse)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a matter of changing `systemctl`.  That is a red herring.  `systemctl` queries the "Policy Kit" to determine whether a particular user, logged on in particular way, is allowed to reboot the system.  You need to change, in Policy Kit, who is permitted to run the `org.freedesktop.login1.reboot` action.  You probably want to change the rules for the three classes of log-on from `yes` to `auth_admin` (or `auth_admin_keep`).

## Further reading

- [How does gnome reboot without root privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216824/5132)
- [Error when running `shutdown -h now`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379027/5132)
- [Is there anything that can be done via a console login, but not via an SSH login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353826/5132)

Comment: Could you expand in your answer on how exactly should I change the rules for the three classes? I have visited all three links you provided, but there is no explanation or examples of how *actually do* what I want.

Comment: I can't believe how complicated it is to configure the system to disallow non-root users from being able to reboot or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to add the following alias in the .bashrc

alias reboot='echo "Your account is not allowed to run the reboot command without sudo"'

Comment: This easy solution worked for me.  Note: I am not trying to make it impossible to run reboot for security reasons, simply I like to accidentally type reboot and lose all my work without expecting it!